# First non-doubled quote pattern

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to create a pattern to match the first non doubled quote in a string.  Everything that isnt a single quote should be ignored.

I have been trying this for ages and dont seem to be getting anywhere.  It is probably very simple.

Best attempt so far: `(?<=[^"])(?<found>")[^"]|(?<=[^"])(?<found>")$|(?<=["]+)(?<found>")$`

Examples:

1. " - match
2. "" - no match
3. """ - match (last quote)
4. "ssdfsdfsfs" - match (first quote)
5. as"sadadas" - match (first quote)
6. as""sadadas" - match (last quote)
7. as""sa""dadas"dfgdfg - match (last quote)

Comment: By "doubled quote", do you mean "pairs of quotes"?
I think there could be confusion about double quote " and single quote '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example for the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism:

```
([\'\"]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\'\"]
```

Praise this elegance: you match everything between two identical quotes in a string (zero or more times) and let the regex engine fail. See [**a demo on regex101.com.**](https://regex101.com/r/x61vnp/1)
(*Note: There's no need to escape the quotes in a character class, just done it for the SO interpreter.*)

---

Now the problem is, this is not supported in `.NET` but you can work a way around it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program {
    static void Main()  {
        string s1 = @"as""""sa""""dadas""dfgdfg - match (last quote)";

        var myRegex = new Regex(@"(['""]).*?\1|(['""])");
        var group1Caps = new StringCollection();

        Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(s1);

        // put Group 1 captures in a list
        while (matchResult.Success) {
            if (matchResult.Groups[1].Value != "") {
                group1Caps.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*** Is there a Match? ***");
        if(group1Caps.Count>0) Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        else Console.WriteLine("No");
    }
}
```

See this [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/ikgwMT).
The basic idea is to ***capture*** what you actually want into the first group and check if this contains anything afterwards. For more information on the subject, have a look at the wonderful [**RexEgg site**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score 0):

Providing a demonstrator in sed, cutting start of line to desired first unpaired quote, inclusive; showing that the right one gets identified:

```
bash-3.1$ sed -En 's/^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*"//;T;p'
```

E.g. output for most interesting sample case 7, as""sa""dadas"dfgdfg:
dfgdfg